# How to use array includes and check an object against a property of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, javascript-objects

I have an array `classTopics` where an object looks like this:

```
{
  questions:2,
  id:49,
  topic:{
    edited: null
    id: 1
    name: "Topic name"
    status: "ACTIVE"
    topicCode:"02"
  }
}
```

And I also have an array `allTopics` where the objects are the same as topic property in the example above:

```
 {
    edited: null
    id: 1
    name: "Topic name"
    status: "ACTIVE"
    topicCode:"02"
  }
```

In the select field I would like to filter all the topics that are the same as a `property topic` in the objects of the `classTopics` array.
So, something like this:

```
 <AutoCompleteSelect
   options={allTopics.filter(topic => !classTopics.includes(topic)).map(({name}) => ({value: name, label: name}))}
 />
```

But, that is not working since it is checking the objects as a whole. How can I do something similar where I could check it against the property on the object?

Basically what I am trying to achieve is this in a nicer way:

```
const filteredTopics = allTopics
                        .filter(topic => 
                          (classTopics.findIndex(classTopic => classTopic.topic.id === topic.id)) === -1);
```

You can find the working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to compare here. Are you just trying to see [if two objects have equal values for each of their keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)?

Comment: No, I am trying to compare the object in the allTopics array agains an object's property topic in the classTopics array

Comment: this typo here `allTopcis` in `AutoCompleteSelect` might be the problem

Comment: Isn't it enough to compare for topic's `id`?

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek but, how to do that when includes compares objects and not just properties?

Comment: @Devashish that was a typo here, but that is not the problem of the question

Comment: add the data for both arrays

Comment: @Leff Something like `allTopics.filter(topic => !classTopics.map(t => t.id).includes(topic.id))`

Comment: @Leff can you include a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Compare by entire object (each property)

You can use `some` to check if the topic is inside the classTopics array, and use `every` with `Object.entries` to check that each property is the same inside the topics array:

```js
const classTopics = [{ questions: 2, id: 49, topic: { edited: null, id: 1, name: "Topic name", status: "ACTIVE", topicCode: "02" }}]
const allTopics = [{ edited: null, id: 1, name: "Topic name", status: "ACTIVE", topicCode: "02" }]

const filterTopics = (a, c) => {
  return a.filter(topic => c
    .some(c => Object.entries(c.topic)
      .every(([k,v]) => topic[k] === v)
    )
  )
}

console.log(filterTopics(allTopics, classTopics))
```

### Compare by ID

As suggested in the comments, checking the entire object is overkill, the purpose of an ID is to identify an object *uniquely* - using ID's makes for a much more efficient solution:

```js
const classTopics = [{ questions: 2, id: 49, topic: { edited: null, id: 1, name: "Topic name", status: "ACTIVE", topicCode: "02" }}]
const allTopics = [{ edited: null, id: 1, name: "Topic name", status: "ACTIVE", topicCode: "02" }]

const filterTopics = (a, c) => a.filter(topic => c.some(t => t.topic.id === topic.id))

console.log(filterTopics(allTopics, classTopics))
```

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer to do this filtering in js file instead of html for simplicity.
Also I am using here [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#pullAllBy) js lib to reduce code size.

```js
const classTopics = [{ questions: 2, id: 49, topic: { edited: null, id: 1, name: "Topic name", status: "ACTIVE", topicCode: "02" }}]
const allTopics = [{ edited: null, id: 1, name: "Topic name", status: "ACTIVE", topicCode: "02" }]

const topicsToshow = _.unionWith(allTopics,classTopics,(cT,aT)=> aT.id===cT.topic.id)
console.log(topicsToshow)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry! My Bad!!
`const topicsToshowa = _.unionWith(allTopics,classTopics,(aT,cT)=> aT.id===cT.topic.id)`
Change last line code to this

Comment: Change your answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can compare just by topic ID, name or other property instead of whole topic objects:

```
allTopics
  .filter(topic => !classTopics.map(t => t.id).includes(topic.id))
  .map(topic => ({value: topic.name, label: topic.name}))
```